# Find two lines contain in the surface $x^2 - y^2 = z$ in a particular point.

Tags: geometry

I know was wondering if we have lines in the point $(a,a,0)$ for some $a\neq 0$ since:
When I establish the system:
$$x + y = kz$$
$$ x - y = 1/k$$
This is not congruent.
So how can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting the parametric equation of a line $(x,y,z) = (a+t u, a+t v, t w)$ into the equation of the surface $x^2 - y^2 = z$ we get $(u^2 - v^2) t^2 + (2au - 2av - w) t = 0$.  In order for this to be true for all $t$ we need $u^2 - v^2 = 0$ (so $u = \pm v$) and $w = 2 a (u-v)$.  One line is obtained with $v=u$, $w=0$, a second with $v=-u$, $w = 4au$.

Here's what the surface and two lines look like:

[image]

Comment: $(+1)$ That moving image is just beautiful. Where did you find it?

Comment: Plotted using the following Maple code:
with(plots):
Surf:= plot3d(x^2-y^2,x=-2..2,y=-2..2,style=patchnogrid):
L1:= spacecurve([1+t,1+t,0],t=-2..1,colour=red):
L2:= spacecurve([1+t,1-t,4*t],t=-1..1,colour=red):
display([Surf,L1,L2],scaling=constrained,axes=none,viewpoint=["circleleft",frames=40],lightmodel=light3);